# C# WebProxy not works with https

Tags: c#, https, webproxy

I have Client + Win service.
Both must work with web server using proxy.
Without proxy all works fine,
 
With system proxy settings (proxy settings from ie)

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy
```

Client works fine, but service don't see this proxy settings (`netsh winhttp set proxy` don't help me). So - proxy server works OK
When I trying to use manual settings:

```
var_proxy = new WebProxy(Server + ":" + Port, true)
            {Credentials = null};
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(target);
        request.ContentType = Constants.ContentType;   // Default content type
        request.UserAgent = _userAgentHeader;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Proxy = _proxy;
```

And as I see in proxy logs - It works with http server, but not used with https! All requests go directly.
How can I fix it?